# How to retrive column names which are byte and not null in C# json web service?

Tags: json, web-services, c#-4.0

I am newb to C#.

I have database table as follow.

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Compulsory_Attachments](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Industry_Id] [int] NULL,
[Forward_letter] [image] NULL,
[Form1] [image] NULL,
[Form1a] [image] NULL,
[Pre_rpt] [image] NULL,
[Project_plan] [image] NULL,
[Parking_plan] [image] NULL,
[EIA_rpt] [image] NULL,
[Mining_Plan] [image] NULL,
[Other_documents] [image] NULL,
[Declaration_page] [image] NULL,
[Project_subtype_masterid] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    )...
```

i want to make a web service method that returns array of string in json format that contains not null column names of industry id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following method

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public String FetchColumns(String id)
{
     int Industry_id = Convert.ToInt32(id);
    SqlConnection objcon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ToString());
    SqlCommand objcmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_Compulsory_Attachments where Industry_Id=" + Industry_id, objcon);
    SqlDataAdapter objda = new SqlDataAdapter(objcmd);
    objcon.Open();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    objda.Fill(ds);
    objcon.Close();


    int i = 0;
    foreach(DataColumn column in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
    {
        foreach (DataRow rs in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            if (rs[column.ColumnName].ToString().Equals("System.Byte[]"))
            {
                if ((byte[])rs[column.ColumnName] != null)
                {
                    i += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ColNames[] columnnames = new ColNames[i];
    int j = 0;
    foreach (DataColumn column in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
    {
        foreach (DataRow rs in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            if (rs[column.ColumnName].ToString().Equals("System.Byte[]"))
            {
                if ((byte[])rs[column.ColumnName] != null)
                {
                    columnnames[j] = new ColNames
                    {
                        id = j,
                        colname = column.ColumnName
                    };
                    j += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(columnnames, Formatting.Indented);

}
```